# How does the browser know which element should get a click or hover event?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

Javascript lets you fire custom events when the user hovers over an element or when a user clicks on an element. But how does Javascript know which elements should receive the click event?

For example an HTML element like this:

```
<div style="width: 300; height: 300;">
    <a href="hello">Hello World</a>
</div>
```

If I click on the link, the browser knows to execute all click events attached to that link. But how does the browser know where on the page the link is (or even that it's visible?)

Consider:

```
<div id="mydiv" style="width: 300; height: 300;">
    <a href="hello">Hello World</a>
</div>
<style>
    #mydiv a {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Now nothing will happen when I click on the space where the link used to be visible. How does the browser know not to fire click/hover events in this case? If I wanted to recreate the algorithm used, what elements would I need?

I assume there is some function in browser code that looks like this:

```
/* Take user's mouse coordinates and return a DOM element. */
function returnElementBasedOnMouseCoordinate(x, y) {

    /* Does a lookup function on some data structure */
    return someElementInTheDom;
}
```

How does that function work?

Comment: The browser knows *everything* about the web-page which is displayed within it. So, if you click anywhere within the web-page, the browser knows what you clicked. So be careful what you click... the browser knows...

Comment: You could start with an [introduction to events](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) at quirksmode (though take it with a grain of salt), then try the [W3C Events spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/). Browsers have a document object model (DOM), so they know exactly where every element and node is in the page and their properties, of all kinds.

Comment: RobG: How does the browser know which element is on top?

Comment: @Kevin - How *doesn't* the browser "know"? The browser created the layout. It is responsible for all of the objects on the page. It knows everything about them. How couldn't it? That's a better question.

Comment: OK... what is the data structure in which top-most (that is, clickable) elements are stored? What does the function that turns x,y coordinates of my mouse into a DOM element to fire an event upon actually do?

Comment: I edited the question to try and make the intent more clear.

Comment: @KevinBurke that is made by the navigator application internally, you can only change it through the event's given to you by the javascript core, which is also implemented by the navigator itself. And, not all the navigators run the same javascript engine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically (meaning WebKit :)) browsers create a **render tree** which roughly corresponds to the document DOM tree but reflects the visual rather than logical structure of the document. For invisible elements (*display: none*), there are no corresponding render objects which participate in mouse event handling. The render tree is modified every time the DOM or some of its visual aspects (element display, visibility, dimensions, etc.) change.

Answer (score 1):

Elements which have `display: none` applied to them (or to their parents) are removed from the layout, so they no longer have any location on the page.

If you're more curious about how HTML layout works in general, a good starting point may be the CSS specification's chapter on the [visual formatting model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html). Once you understand that, understanding how events are fired is relatively straightforward -- events are sent first to the element which has the highest z-index and contains the point you clicked on. (In the case you're asking about here, again: `#mydiv` has no location, so it can't contain the point you clicked on.)